# How to update the SQLite version bundled with PHP

Tags: php, windows, sqlite, pdo

PHP 5.5 comes bundled with SQLite 3.7.7.1.

There have been ~ 20 newer releases of SQLite since then, and www.sqlite.org recommends to upgrade. In my case, I need a feature available only since SQLite 3.8.0.

As far as I understood, SQLite is not dynamically linked in PHP 5.5 but the sqlite source code is compiled into the built-in PHP PDO driver for SQLite.

Is there a way to use a current SQLite version in PHP without rebuilding PHP from source (e.g., somehow dynamically linking sqlite.dll)?

Comment: recompile your php-sqlite using latest version of libsqlite in your *nix OS. thats all.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. so I would manually copy the current sqlite source code into the PHP source tree and then create a new version of 'php_sqlite3.dll' and 'php_pdo_sqlite.dll'? "with *nix OS" => you mean I should cross-compile on Unix (cygwin?) for windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I could produce a fresh php_pdo_sqlite.dll to drop into an existing PHP 5.5 Windows installation that includes the current version (3.8.1) of SQLite:

I followed the nice [step-by-step guide](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) to build PHP on Windows using Visual Studio 2012 Express (available from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34673).

In the PHP 5.5 sources, I have replaced the outdated sqlite amalgamation file `ext\sqlite3\libsqlite\sqlite.c` by the current one from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html.

I used `configure --enable-pdo=shared --with-pdo-sqlite=shared`.

This creates `php_pdo_sqlite.dll` that I could drop into an existing PHP 5.5 installation, replacing the previous (bundled) version of that file.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:test1.sqlite');
print_r("SQLite version " . $dbh->query('select sqlite_version()')->fetch()[0]);
$dbh = null;
?>
```

confirms:

```
SQLite version: 3.8.1
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Now I just need to enable RTREE and I'm done!