# Syntax error in creating trigger in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, syntax, triggers

The following code causes a syntax error in SQLite. 
I imagine this must be simple but I can't see it.

I have two tables, pages and items, linked through a text code. When this code in changed in pages table, I want it changed in items table too.

The SQLite version is quite old, 3.7.7.1,  but I haven't seen such a problem in version history. This occurs on Windows, with PHP 5.3.1.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "efpage" ( "pageid" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "psite" text NULL, "pgcode" text NULL ); 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "efitem" ( "itemid" integer NULL PRIMARY KEY , "isite" text NULL, "ititle" text NULL,  "inpage" text NULL); 

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_pagecode;
CREATE TRIGGER update_pagecode AFTER UPDATE OF pgcode ON efpage
BEGIN
UPDATE efitem SET inpage = new.pgcode WHERE inpage = old.pgcode;
END;
```

The resulting error is 
ERROR near "pgcode": syntax error.

Trying different things, I saw that the syntax error is after "old.pgcode;"

Comment: Works for me (3.8.9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by CL,

this is linked to the version of SQLite.
I use SQLite bundled with PHP on windows.

The next (answered) question for me is :

[How to update the SQLite version bundled with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20327844/how-to-update-the-sqlite-version-bundled-with-php)